# Connect to AWS S3 From Presto

Tags: amazon-s3, presto, presto-jdbc, opera-presto

Connect to AWS S3 Using presto connector :

I had followed the documentation provided by presto , but however I couldnt able to , I tried the below configuration :

https://prestodb.io/docs/current/connector/hive.html#s3-configuration-properties

```
connector.name=hive-hadoop2
hive.metastore.uri=thrift:mariadb://md7wf1g369xf22.cluz8hwxjhb6.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306
hive.s3.endpoint=https://databricks-workspace-stack-3545e-metastore-bucket.s3-us-east-2.amazonaws.com
hive.s3.aws-access-key=
hive.s3.aws-secret-key=
```

Can someone let me know what exactly I am missing

I tried the below configuration :

https://prestodb.io/docs/current/connector/hive.html#s3-configuration-properties

Comment: check the URL Please as not pointing the right link

Comment: @KarthikeyanRasipalayDurairaj   updated the right link

Comment: are you trying in databricks Rajesh ?

Comment: @KarthikeyanRasipalayDurairaj  : databricks-workspace-stack-3545e-metastore-bucket.s3-us-east-2.amazonaws.com  is my S3 bucket details

Comment: @Rajeshm The hive connector config you are using not valid. It has to be Presto-> Hive -> MariaDB metastore(RDS). Can you confirm if your Hive is working fine? If yes then provide valid Hive config in Hive catalog configuration .